# Closing specific NSDocument instance with notifications

Tags: objective-c, notifications, nsnotifications, nsdocument

I have the following issue. I am trying to reproduce an XCode-like "new project" workflow in a small IDE I build. For this I have a sheet that runs modal in the window created by the doc window controller when user selects "New project". The sheet is inited from a nib and loads several subviews (via view controllers) in a stepwise approach, to set up the project (type -> parameters ... etc) to the point of saving the new project. So far so good.

The problem I have is when I try to cancel the process BEFORE saving. I cannot figure how to close the modal sheet and the doc instance WITHOUT closing other doc instances (aka "projects") that might be opened.

My app has a delegate, a NSDocument class that is controlled via a NSWindowController and several other controllers and nibs. For now, I am thinking of implementing a notification-based approach in the application delegate, but I cannot get to a grip.

I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Warmest regards,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also call an action method when the cancel button is pressed. This way the action method manages to close the sheet and close your NSDocument subclass instance.

Comment: Hi, Vince. Thanks for your answer. I have an action method. But the button is in a subview of the sheet (loaded dynamically). The sheet being modal, I cannot capture the action otherwise than in this subview. Thus, I try to find a way to connect this action with the actual document close method, only for the instance with the modal sheet displayed.

Comment: Try using the `setAction:(SEL)anAction` of your `NSControl`. Also set the target to nil so the action message go through the responder chain.

Comment: Hi, Vince. Thanks for tip. I'll try.

Comment: Hi, yes, it works. I completely, completely forgot about `sendAction: to: from:` and the responder chain goodies. Which made my day. Thank you for help. Warmest regards, Tom

Comment: Sorry for not answering earlier. But I indulged myself in Kochan's book. Such a fabulous lecture !